# I write a the merge sort, but it has some bug

Tags: c++, mergesort

i write small project to implement **merge sort**. This is my code:

```
template <typename T>
void merge(T arr[], int begin, int mid, int end)
{
    int len = end - begin + 1;
    T *temp = new T[len];
    int i = begin;
    int j = mid + 1;
    int k = 0;
    while (i <= mid && j <= end)
    {
        if(arr[i] <= arr[j])
            temp[k++] = arr[i++];
        else
            temp[k++] = arr[j++];
    }
    while (i <= mid)
        temp[k++] = arr[i++];
    while(j <= end)
        temp[k++] = arr[j++];

    memcpy(arr + begin, temp, len*sizeof(T));
}


//merge sort
template <typename T>
void mergeSort(T arr[], int begin, int end)
{
    if (begin >= end)
        return;

    int mid = (end + begin) / 2;
    mergeSort(arr, begin, mid);
    mergeSort(arr, mid + 1, end);
    merge(arr, begin, mid, end);
}

int main()
{
    const int N = 10;
    int arr[N];
    for_each(arr, arr + N, [](int &val){ val = rand() % 100; });

    copy(arr, arr+N, ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    cout<<endl;

    mergeSort(arr, 0, N - 1);

    copy(arr, arr+N, ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    cout<<endl;
}
```

sometime i got the right answer, sometime i got wrong answer.
this problem confuses me a lot of time, when can help find the bug?

Comment: You are generating random numbers for your array.  I don't believe the standard says that `rand()` must perform equivalently on all platforms...

Comment: i find it's my code's bug. my merge sort have some bug.

Comment: That, and the fact that the sort doesn't actually work.

Comment: I suggest using a smaller array, filled with values you know, and use a debugger to step through the code to find the problem.

Comment: Also, I hope you're doing this only as an exercise, because [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) should work fine.

Comment: When using `for_each`, `copy`, `ostream_iterator`, and *lambdas*, it's actually a pity to see `new T[len]` when you have `array` and `vector` available. It would have saved you from a memory leak!

Comment: And as a last point, if a program behaves differently when compiled with different compilers, it's most likely due to undefined behavior in your code. I suggest you add more warnings flags as they often can help indicate cases of undefined behavior. `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` is a good start.

Comment: @DidierTrosset Not to mention that the OP uses `std::copy` is some places and `std::memcpy` in others, and other similar things.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes , rand() implementation is different in both platforms, It is an old post in stackoverflow,pls refer [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958795/different-rand-results-on-windows-and-linux)

Answer (score 0):

The mistake you made in your code, is when you calculate the length of your array to sort. Indeed `int len = end - begin;` gives you a length of 9, whereas your array contains 10 elements.

You should be careful when sending indexes to the functions. All `std::` functions works with iterators, and the `end` iterator always indicates one past the last element.

I suggest you change your code with this in mind, trying to call `mergeSort(arr, 0, N);` in your main, having other functions behaving correctly.

Comment: you are wrong. if i use mergeSort(arr, 0, N); i got this result,
-858993460 -858993460 0 24 24 34 41 24 58 58

Comment: @BlackMamba I didn't meant that you only have to change 9 to 10 in the main. All other functions should be changed as-well! However, you should be consistent in the use of begin and end values. The best for this being to be consistent with the C++ std library. The issue with your mergeSort algorithm probably lies somewhere with these indexes...